# Texture mapping for projecting letters on surfaces

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry, texture-mapping

I want to apply a texture (that in my case it is a simple text hence a set of parametric curves) on a 3D surface.

The result that I would like to obtain is depicted in the following picture:

[image: here]

I think that it is a widely known problem to 3D programmers, so I would like to know a simple algorithm to achieve this task.

Comment: Please be more specific. What is your input? What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, you are right :)
Input:1) a surface (triangolar mesh or NURB); 2) a set of parametric curves each expressed by control points;
Output: the give set of parametric curves "projected" (as depicted) on the surface

Comment: you need to add UV space coordinates, then create 2D texture with your text and render your object with text... If you use raytracing then you need to specify this as that is whole another problem ...